# Apt-get stopped working

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, apt-get, apt

Relatively new to Linux but I've become comfortable enough with the terminal.However recently with any "apt-get install" I get this in response `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

When I try `apt-get -f install` I get `Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`. I looked around but couldn't find much, sorry about the vagueness.

Comment: running the following command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get -f install ` should help you move forward

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo autoremove -y && sudo apt-get clean
```

It could be an issue with the update files.